# Retrieve Structure Top Level Pages

Tags: structure, navigation

I find myself struggling with some of Structure's documentation and cannot find an answer via Google either, here's the skinny:

Currently have 2 top level "pages" (2 more but are hidden because I dont need them in the nav list). Each of these have children pages and everything is dandy and working.

```
Top Level Page1 - overview template / Channel1
    + Child Page -- Display template / Channel2
    + Child Page -- Display template / Channel2

Top Level Page2 - overview template / Channel1
    + Child Page -- Display template / Channel2
    + Child Page -- Display template / Channel2
```

I now need to take those 2 "top" level pages and insert them into a select dropdown for some JS sorting on a page that isn't managed by Structure, like this:

```
Project Overview -- show all entries template - Channel2
    {exp:channel:entries}
    // Works well, spits out Channel2 data no prob
    //This is what I need
    <option value="{structure:parent:id}">structure:parent:name</option>
```

Have tried:

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/" max_depth="1"}
  <option value="{page_uri}">{title}</option>
{/exp:structure:nav}
//This code works well in nav
```

This yields nothing (blank code), the docs allude that using :nav sets an li which I dont want & likely causing nothing to output.

I expect because Structure isn't managing the "projects" page, finding a parent or anything to do with normal `exp:channel:entries` tag is the roadblock.

Thought about adding Top Level pages as children of a new 'parent' but then I'd have another list item in the main nav which we dont want.

Totally stumped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested and for my future self, I basically need to add id's to 2 select dropdpowns (1 for category and for one to identity which parent it belongs to)  + also replicate on 2 data values for each entry.

This is all outside the Structure framework, I'm querying only the children entries with a simple exp:channel:entries but no native way to query who its parent is.

```
/* Simple enough to add top value entry_ids
<select name="disciplines" data-label="Filter by Disciplines">
  <option selected="selected" value="all">All Disciplines</option>
  {exp:structure_entries depth="1" hide_from_nav="yes"}
    <option value="{entry_id}">{title}</option>
  {/exp:structure_entries}
</select>

/* Bit of a no brainer getting the categories
<select name="market" data-label="Filter by Market">
<option selected="selected" value="all">All Markets</option>
  {exp:gwcode_categories style="linear" channel="project_detail" show_empty="no"}
    <option value="{cat_url_title}">{cat_name}</option>
  {/exp:gwcode_categories}
</select>
```

Now the fun part, mighty Croxton Stash + Structure Entries FTW

```
/* Simple list of relationships !!
{exp:stash:set_list name="associated" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
    {exp:structure_entries  hide_from_nav="yes" parse="inward"}
        {stash:parentid}{parent_id}{/stash:parentid}
        {stash:entryid}{entry_id}{/stash:entryid}
    {/exp:structure_entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

THE MAGIC = match + against !!

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project_detail"}
<article data-disciplines="{exp:stash:get_list name='associated' match='#{entry_id}#' against='entryid'}{parentid},{/exp:stash:get_list}"
data-market="{exp:gwcode_categories entry_id='{entry_id}' style='linear' backspace='1'}{cat_url_title},{/exp:gwcode_categories}">
... remainder of layout for product ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the [Structure Entries add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-entries) for this. Here's the basic idea (full docs can be found at the devot-ee page):

```
<select id="Menu" name="menu">
  {exp:structure_entries  depth="1"}
    <option value="{page_uri}" {if {current_page}}selected{/if}>{title}</option>
  {/exp:structure_entries}
</select>
```

Comment: That's 99% of the way there, any thoughts on how to hide the Parent I have already hidden ?

Comment: Try this: {exp:structure_entries depth="1" hide_from_nav="yes"} taken from https://getsatisfaction.com/twobelowzero/topics/hide_from_nav_variable

Comment: So damn close but no cigar. Really need to nest inside an exp:channel tag and only output info for the current entry_id, adding entry_id="XX" to the tag does nothing :(

Comment: I guess I'm not fully grasping what you need to accomplish. Per my last comment it outputs a select menu with all top-levl nav items *not hidden* (in my test it works great) but your last comment has me confused.

Comment: Try using the "include" and "exclude" parameters instead to manually specify pages to list and not list.

Comment: The module works but first post didn't adequately  explain situation. Could get id's or anything else into area outside of channel entries but inside or as a replacement for exp:channel it didnt work. The parents are dynamic hence cant include/exclude because its dynamic :)